# Javascript: replace all instances of <br> that appear between multiple sets of brackets

Tags: javascript

I have a string with multiple sets of brackets, and each set of brackets contains multiple `<br>` tags. For instance, one snippet might read:

```
<p>some text<br>[text<br> text text<br>text]<br>some more text<br>[text]</p>
```

I need to remove the `<br>` tags within the brackets, but not the `<br>` tags outside of the brackets.  I tried doing this with .replace and a .indexOf() loop, but it deleted the `<br>` tags outside of the brackets.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: use regular expression to target the items you need to replace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regular expression and replace while it matches the `<br>` in brackets:

```
var regexp = /\[(.*)<br>(.*)\]/; // [anything<br>anything]

while(regexp.test(str)) {
  str = str.replace(regexp, "[$1$2]"); // replace with [anythinganything]
}
```

Comment: it is important to notice that the looping is required as javascript's string.replace only replaces the first occurrence of a match

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for the fast response.